# How to enable drop shadows in plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, kwin, plasma-5

Kubuntu 15.04
Plasma 5.3+
Kwin 5+

I cannot find the setting to enable drop shadows.
Or is there no setting for that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

System Settings -> Application Style -> Window Decorations and click on the  icon settings for the window theme selected (in my case is Breeze). There is a tab named Shadows, you can change some values.

If after all the window shadow isn't showing, maybe you have to (re)enable Compositor, at System Settings -> Hardware -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor. For me, OpenGL 3.1 is working well for the Rendering backend .

Comment: Setting the size to 48px, strength to 60% and color to #272727 seems to give a nice effect. Too bad it's not possible to adjust position, since it's mostly visible only on the lower and right side.

Comment: dang that is a lot of work digging just to disable these crazy useless eye candy to free up some compute

Comment: I did this but it is still weak compared to Deepin or eOS

Comment: Re-enabling compositor was the key here (it usually crashes from time to time ;(